# Conda custom channel on windows

Tags: windows, conda

I've created a custom channel on a windows box following the steps detailed [here](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/custom-channels.html).

Now I'd like to access it from a different machine but the channel parameter is a URI and I don't know what form it should take with Windows.

Here's the command I tried to execute:

```
conda search -c file://machine\C\channel --override-channels scipy
```

which failed with the following error message:

> Fetching package metadata: Error: Invalid index file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say that your custom channel is located in the following directory:
`N:\conda\channel`. Then we would expect to see the following in this directory (1) the `win-64` directory (2) the index files inside, in this case the directory `N:\conda\channel\win-64\`, of `repodata.json` and `repodata.json.bz2` (3) any packages that you have added to your channel.  A search on this channel for the scipy package, ignoring all other channels, would look like this `conda search -c file://N:\conda\channel --override-channels scipy`

Did you add the `scipy` package into your custom channel? If you did, then did you run `conda index` on that directory?

I'm a little confused by your directory structure but, if your channel is `machine\C\channel`, then what happens when you do `dir machine\C\channel`?

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to use a UNC instead of having to map a drive?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, not that I'm aware of.  Using a UNC didn't work for me either.

Comment: Yes, UNC paths are possible -- see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

I have been trying to do the same thing, and the [answer by Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36409267/212538) made me a bit pessimistic.

It turns out that it is possible to use a UNC-path.
After trying a few hundred combinations of slashes and backslashes, I found this combination to work:

```
conda search -c "file://\\DOMAIN\SERVER\SHARE\conda\channel" --override-channels
```

Similarly,

```
conda config --add channels "file://\\DOMAIN\SERVER\SHARE\conda\channel"
```

Adds the channel to your config file.

Answer (score 3):

I had no success with the other answers though [@gDexter42](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40878143/3585557) helped me in the right direction.  Perhaps the API has changed.  Testing several different options I was somewhat surprised that

- you can use `/` or `\` interchangably
- you do not need to escape spaces
- you do not need to enclose paths with spaces in quotes

After creating a [custom channel](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/create-custom-channels.html#creating-custom-channels) in a network accessible directory, you can search for a conda package using the file path, excluding the `file://` mentioned in other posts and in [the documentation](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/create-custom-channels.html#creating-custom-channels).

For a UNC Path:

```
$ conda search -c //my_nas/some/path with spaces/channel --override-channels
```

or 
    $ conda search -c \my_nas\some\path with spaces\channel --override-channels

If the folder is local, or you have mounted a network directory to a local path (`D:\` in this example), you would use that file path.

```
$ conda search -c D:/some/path with spaces/channel --override-channels
```

or

```
$ conda search -c D:\some\path with spaces\channel --override-channels
```

I tested these commands using both [Git Bash for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) and Anaconda Prompt (which I think is just `cmd.exe` with the path modified so `base`/`root` is the active environment).

Note that if you then want to add that path to your `.condarc` file, you can use the same path.

`channels:
  - \\my_nas\some\path with spaces\channel  # UNC
  - D:/some/path with spaces/channel  # local drive
  - defaults  # this gives defaults lower priority
ssl_verify: true`

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to search for a conda package in a local directory (not on UNC), the following two approaches worked for me.

1. Navigate to the drive containing the package and try

`conda search -c file://folder_path/channel --override-channels`

2. the better way is to drop the `file` flag which allows you to search from any drive. Type

`conda search -c Drive://folder_path/channel --override-channels` thus if you are searching from `D:` drive you would type this as
`conda search -c D://folder_path/channel --override-channels`

Comment: (base) C:\Users\user>conda search -c C://Temp//my-conda--override-channels --override-channels
Loading channels: failed

UnavailableInvalidChannel: The channel is not accessible or is invalid.
  channel name: C://Temp//my-conda--override-channels
  channel url: https://conda.anaconda.org/C://Temp//my-conda--override-channels
  error code: 404

Answer (score 0):

If your conda channel is at C:\conda-channel then do:

```
conda search -c file://\conda-channel --override-channels
```

There is currently a bug in conda 4.6+ where `file://C:\conda-channel` will not work as it removes the colon when parsing. And downgrading to 4.5 is dangerous and can mess up your installation.